# How to compile typescript using npm command?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I just wanted to know is there any command which will directly compile the typescript code and get the output. Right now, what I am doing is, every time when I make changes in the file I have to re-run the command in order to compile it

```
npm start
```

This starts the browser and then I have to stop the execution using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and then I have to run the file using the npm command

```
node filename
```

to see the output.

So what I want to know is, is there any npm command which will compile the .ts file and see the changes which I have made in the file while I run the file using the

```
node filename
```

command

Comment: You should read about task runners or just add `tsc app.ts` to `npm start` of `package.json`

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can launch the `tsc` command (typescript compiler) with `--watch` argument.

Here is an idea :

- Configure typescript using `tsconfig.json` file
- Run `tsc --watch`, so every time you change a `.ts` file, `tsc` will compile it and produce the output (let say you configured typescript to put the output in `./dist` folder)
- Use `nodemon` to watch if files in `./dist` have changed and if needed to relaunch the server.

Here are some scripts (to put in `package.json`) that can help you to do it (you will need to install the following modules `npm install --save typescript nodemon npm-run-all rimraf`)

```
"scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf dist",
    "start": "npm-run-all clean --parallel watch:build watch:server --print-label",
    "watch:build": "tsc --watch",
    "watch:server": "nodemon './dist/index.js' --watch './dist'"
}
```

Then you just need to run `npm start` in a terminal

Comment: This doesn't work for me, because `nodemon` is trying to start the server before `watch:build` task has finished. I get an error from nodemon saying: `Cannot find module '.../dist/index.js`

Comment: You may need to add nodemon, npm-run-all, and rimraf to packages.json `npm i rimraf npm-run-all nodemon --save-dev`

Comment: `tsc` is the typescript compiler. It comes when you install typescript with `npm install typescript`. You can also use it with `npx tsc`. You can find more information [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)

Answer (score 14):

This is based on solution proposed by @ThomasThiebaud. I had to modify it a little to make sure the files are built in `dist/` before nodemon tries to start the server.

```
"scripts": {
    "clean": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "tsc",
    "watch:build": "tsc --watch",
    "watch:server": "nodemon './dist/index.js' --watch './dist'",
    "start": "npm-run-all clean build --parallel watch:build watch:server --print-label"
  },
```

You still need to run `npm start` to start the whole thing.

Answer (score 11):

Here is my approach, let say that you keep all your `typescript` files in `src` folder and want outputted `javascript` files be generated in the `./dist` folder.

```
{
    "name": "yourProjectName",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "./dist/index",
    "types": "./dist/index",
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "tsc --watch & nodemon dist"
    },
    "author": "Gh111",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "yourdevDependencies": "^1.0.0"
    }
}
```

and typescript configuration file `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",       
    "module": "commonjs",  
    "outDir": "./dist",    
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*"],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Okay, what is going on here

First of all we should create `tsconfig.json` and tell typescript to put compiled files into the `./dist` folder and at the same time we should exclude `node_module` folder or whatever we want and include everything from `["./src/**/*"]` directory.

After that in `packages.json` file we should specify path to our compiled `index.js` file

> "main": "./dist/index"

and finally we tell `tsc` to `--watch` any `typescript` changes, and `nodemon` to watch inside `./dist` directory and if something changes `nodemon` will restart the server.

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "tsc --watch & nodemon dist"
 },
```

To run script type `npm run dev`

Comment: This approach work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Compiling TypeScript

tsc filename.ts | node filename.js  (for windows user).

tsc filename.ts && node filename.js (for Mac user).

Answer (score 0):

```js
"scripts": {
  "dev": "nodemon",
  "build": "npm install && npx tsc",
  "start": "node ./dist/index.js",
  "local": "env-cmd -f .env.e2e npm run dev"
},
```

To run script type `npm run build`, make sure you have typescript configuration file `tsconfig.json`.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",       
    "module": "commonjs",  
    "outDir": "./dist",    
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*"],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```