# Unable to get TypeScript watching my project and nodemon reloading it

Tags: node.js, typescript, nodemon

Command  `tsc -w -p server` watch the `server` directory compile TypeScript into `dist/server` folder (`dist/server/app.js` is the main Node script).

Command `nodemon -w dist/server dist/server/app.js` watches `dist/server` folder and reloads `dist/server/app.js` when something changes.

The problem: if I run both **commands in parallel**, `tsc` will take some times but `nodemon` starts too soon, when `dist/server/app.js` doesn't exist yet.

```
concurrently \"tsc -w -p server\" \"nodemon -w dist/server dist/server/app.js\"
```

On the other hand, if I run the **commands sequentially** I lost `nodemon` output (that is, the server output) because `tsc` will watch for changes and "steal" the console ouput:

```
tsc -w -p server\ && nodemon -w dist/server dist/server/app.js
```

I've tested both these strategies with [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon) and [npm-run-all](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all), a popular alternative.

Related questions (accepted answer doesn't solve the problem):

- [Is there a way to use npm scripts to run tsc -watch && nodemon --watch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38276862/is-there-a-way-to-use-npm-scripts-to-run-tsc-watch-nodemon-watch)

Comment: Another possible set of answers for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41853422/how-to-compile-typescript-using-npm-command

Answer (score 0):

Adding a delay of 1000ms to `nodemon` fixed the issue for me.

https://github.com/remy/nodemon#delaying-restarting

**nodemon.json**

```
{
  "watch": ["build"],
  "ext": "js",
  "exec": "npm start",
  "delay": 1000
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "demo",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node build/index.js",
    "ts": "tsc -w",
    "nodemon": "nodemon",
    "code": "concurrently -n ts,nodemon npm:ts npm:nodemon"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^4.1.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.9",
    "typescript": "^3.2.2"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "build",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "node_modules/*",
        "src/types/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

`npm run code`