# Heroku at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed"

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, heroku, typeorm

I'm having this error, when I try to access my api on heroku

I have project with nodejs, typescript, typeORM and using database with Postgresql.

link for my project: https://github.com/WesleyIsr4/tarefas_api/tree/main/tasks_api

```
2021-03-24T23:42:04.841420+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-03-24T23:42:06.805718+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-03-24T23:42:06.805731+00:00 app[web.1]: > tasks_api@0.0.1 start /app
2021-03-24T23:42:06.805731+00:00 app[web.1]: > node src/index.ts
2021-03-24T23:42:06.805731+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-03-24T23:42:06.871406+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:21) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
2021-03-24T23:42:06.871407+00:00 app[web.1]: (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
2021-03-24T23:42:06.874166+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/src/index.ts:1
2021-03-24T23:42:06.874166+00:00 app[web.1]: import "reflect-metadata";
2021-03-24T23:42:06.874167+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^
2021-03-24T23:42:06.874167+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-03-24T23:42:06.874168+00:00 app[web.1]: SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
2021-03-24T23:42:06.874168+00:00 app[web.1]: at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:16)
2021-03-24T23:42:06.874169+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:27)
2021-03-24T23:42:06.874169+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
2021-03-24T23:42:06.874170+00:00 app[web.1]: at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
2021-03-24T23:42:06.874170+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
2021-03-24T23:42:06.874171+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
2021-03-24T23:42:06.874171+00:00 app[web.1]: at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
2021-03-24T23:42:06.889434+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2021-03-24T23:42:06.889834+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2021-03-24T23:42:06.896276+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! tasks_api@0.0.1 start: `node src/index.ts`
2021-03-24T23:42:06.896419+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2021-03-24T23:42:06.896567+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2021-03-24T23:42:06.896657+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the tasks_api@0.0.1 start script.
2021-03-24T23:42:06.896771+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2021-03-24T23:42:06.905764+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-03-24T23:42:06.906023+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-03-24T23:42:06.906187+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-03-24T23_42_06_897Z-debug.log
2021-03-24T23:42:06.952487+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-03-24T23:42:07.022497+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-03-24T23:42:07.716132+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=taskedapi.herokuapp.com request_id=cb3a7f47-103e-408d-874b-c0e3466eead5 fwd="177.37.210.66" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-03-24T23:42:08.350324+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=taskedapi.herokuapp.com request_id=ead9cb26-9b21-4d6e-9630-70b13306d777 fwd="177.37.210.66" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Answer (score 0):

Node can't run typescript (.ts) files. You're going to need to either:

- use something like [ts-node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59587296/how-to-deploy-a-typescript-nodejs-and-express-app-to-heroku) to compile the files
- [compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41853422/how-to-compile-typescript-using-npm-command/41854500) your .ts files to .js as part of your deployment steps

Answer (score 0):

For everybody parachuted here...

In your package.json you have to change your scripts to:

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "start": "node dist/server.js",
    ...other scripts may be put here too
  },
```

When deployed, heroku will execute **build** script, transpiling your typescript to javascript, then it will execute **start** script.
Note that **start** script will run your **.js** file, not the original **.ts**.

It is important to say that **start** script must point to your server.js file found in **dist** folder(created during deployiment), not to server.ts from your **src** folder.

Heroku docs say you have to put a **main** key in package.json too as shown:

```
  "main": "server.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
  ...
```

My answer may be late for the OP, but complement @Jim's answer